# fs.writeFile and other methods freezing azure web app

Tags: node.js, azure

I have an azure web app within which I have a simple logger service to write out certain errors to a log file I can later retrieve. The below code works in the sense that it does create/append to the file - but the web app then seems to 'freeze' in the sense that any future http request will require the web app to start up again. The strange thing is that no errors are thrown and nothing is output in the console to suggest a problem.

This works fine locally so I am assuming there's something about Azure that's causing this?

```
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const logFile = 'error-logs.log'

class Logger {
    constructor() { }

    log(input) {
        let now = new Date();
        console.log(input);
        let logString = `${now.toUTCString()}:\n${util.inspect(input)}\n`
        fs.appendFile(logFile, logString, err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("----LOGGER ERROR----");
                console.log(err);
            }
            console.log(`this error has been logged to ${logFile}`);
        });
    }
}
```

#### edit 1

Also worth noting that it's not limited to just this function, a similarly simple function has the same symptoms - that is: it does it's job (in this case, clearing the file) but then the next request to the web app causing it to start up again

```
clear() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(logFile, '', err => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("----LOGGER ERROR----");
                console.log(err);
                reject(err);
            }
            console.log('log file cleared');
            resolve('log file cleared');
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I wonder what happens if `input` has circular object references in it?  Does `util.inspect()` infinite loop?

Comment: It defaults to 2 levels deep, so would stop even in this case. Worth adding (will edit Q) that a simple writeFile call has the same problem

Comment: Try putting a `try/catch` around things and see if it gets to the `catch()` just to see if there are any exceptions being thrown that aren't getting logged for some reason.

Comment: Done - and nope no errors

Comment: OK, what you're describing is not something node.js can do on its own so you have some sort of system weirdness going on.  I have no idea.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts - but my understanding of Azure is very limited so I'm shooting in the dark and google has been no help! thanks for the effort.